# Is this a good abstract algebra text?

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request

I will start university next year and I want to prepare for abstract algebra. I was recommended a book called "basic abstract algebra, by Jain, Nagpaul et al", but I don't know how good this is for a beginner. I have an online version of this book and am willing to send it to your email if you want.

Note: This question is very specific and hasn't been asked before, please don't close.

Thanks

Comment: The description on Amazon says it's for "senior undergraduate and ... graduate students".  So it's probably not going to be a good fit for you.

Comment: I used Knapp's *Basic Algebra* and Artin's *Algebra* together and I really liked the combo.  Another good one is Fraleigh's *A* *First* *Course* *in* *Abstract* *Algebra*.

Comment: I don't know about this but I am currently doing introduction to abstract algebra we are using Elements of modern algebra by Linda gilbert and Jimmie gilbert it is perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra by Joseph A. Gallian"*.

I personally love the text, (the questions even more) *but keep one thing in mind, you won't understand the text until you solve most of the exercise problems*. Well, that's how to learn to apply things, isn't it?

**EDIT:** I took a look over the book and it seems to be good. But I'd say you should stick with some "elementary" text first. Then move on to this book. The text isn't much different *(maybe, when you've read a topic, all the books look almost the same)*, just the chapters reordered. In the book, the author goes from Groups to homomorphisms directly *(and gives relatively less examples)*, though what I would want in a book would be proper *"order?"* Groups$\to$Abelian/Cyclic Groups$\to$Homomorphism(much later). I'd still go with the book I mentioned above.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: @RghtHndSd: Yes, I understand. I should probably ask her/him for the ebook.

Comment: Your answer has two vague statements of opinion with no justification. What does "good" mean here? Why is it "good"? Why do you recommend an "elementary" text first? When someone asks a question on here to calculate a definite integral, you don't respond with "5", you respond with your work supporting it. Please do the same here.

Comment: @RghtHndSd: Now is it up to the mark?

Comment: Well, you mention that it has less examples, and that is certainly a reason. So that's something. Having something be "a matter of my tastes" is a terrible reason to say to someone else because it is completely meaningless and opinionated.